# How can I hide scrollbar in IE but still can scroll? in chrome and safari can use ::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, scrollbar

How can I hide scroll bar in IE but still can scroll? In chrome and safari can use : `:-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}` ,it worked,but not work in IE, I need to solve this problem is that the emergence of the scroll bar will affect the layout of the page.

Stick out a mile

[image: Screenshot]